# Rails 3 cannot serve assets in production from apache server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, production

Using Rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9.2 and I am not able to serve assets in production.  Not really experienced in configuring servers for webapps.

I have the following code in applictation.html.erb,

```
  <a href="/"><img src="/assets/topbar.png" border="0" alt="My LOGO"></a>
```

I put topbar.png in app/assets/images/.  It works as expected in development mode, shows up when the png is there, does not show up if I delete the png.

It does not show up in production. We have done the following, so far.  The app does run, but it does not show the above asset.

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
  ServerName dev.mycompany.com:8081
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.mycompany.com/webapps/
#        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.mycompany.com/webapps/testapp/public
#   PassengerLogLevel 3

        RackBaseURI /myRailsTest
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dev.mycompany.com/webapps/myRailsTest>
                AllowOverride all
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                    php_admin_flag engine on
                    php_admin_flag safe_mode on
             </IfModule>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I have to do something more to configure the apache server? I'm  reading this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, but finding it pretty dense for a newbie.

What can I try?  One thing I read is: "You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served.  In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by default."  But actually, I can't see that it is doing that for me.  Is that the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: On the server try something like RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this section of rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Precompile your assets with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
2. Live compilation: `config.assets.compile = true`

And you should use `image_tag` to create `<img>` helper in your layouts and views, because during the precompilation phase an MD5 is generated from the contents of the compiled files, and inserted into the filenames as they are written to disc.

Comment: Thank you, image_tag was the key for my situation.  Thanks!